# Why does Mathematica neglect this special case for a double integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I was running the following script in Mathematica

`f = Sin[n*Pi*q]*Sin[m*Pi*p]*Exp[I*b*(q - p)] + Sin[n*Pi*q]*Sin[m*Pi*p]*Exp[-I*b*(q - p)]
integral = Integrate[Integrate[f, {p, 0, q}], {q, 0, 1}]
SimpleIntegral = Simplify[integral, n ∈ Integers && m ∈ Integers]
SimpleIntegral /. n -> m`

and noticed that the resulting double integral was incorrect for the special case `n=m`. In fact the result is singular at `m=n`.

My question is **why does Mathematica not account for this special case? Is there any way to force it to distinguish the cases?** Right now I have to compute the `m=n` case separately and then synthesize my own formula from the two results.

---

For clarity what I really want to compute is the integral
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^q \left[\sin(n\pi q)\sin(m\pi p)e^{ib(q - p)} + \sin(n\pi q)\sin(m\pi p)e^{-ib(q - p)}\right]$$

under the condition that $n$ and $m$ are integers. $n$ and $m$ may or may not be equal.

---

To see why this integral is indeed wrong for the special case `n=m` try the following code, where the assumption is put at the start and that gives a finite result

`f = Sin[n*Pi*q]*Sin[n*Pi*p]*Exp[I*b*(q - p)] + 
  Sin[n*Pi*q]*Sin[n*Pi*p]*Exp[-I*b*(q - p)]
integral = Integrate[Integrate[f, {p, 0, q}], {q, 0, 1}]
SimpleIntegral = Simplify[integral, n ∈ Integers]`

Comment: Why is `integral` alternatively capitalized?

Comment: I get, `FullSimplify[integral, 
  n \[Element] Integers && m \[Element] Integers] /. n -> m`.. `Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. >>` as expected.

Comment: @Feyre oops, the capitalized 'integral' was a typo. I corrected it, the script should run now. About the other comment: yep, I get that too. That is really not expected though, how is the integral with n=m infinite? Also I tried setting n=m at the start and then compute the integral, that gave a different and finite result.

Comment: @Feyre see edit, does that clarify?

Comment: *Mathematica* will usually only generate *[generically correct](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GenericAndNonGenericCases.html)* answers.

Comment: @J.M. ah I see, thanks! That answers **why does Mathematica not account for this special case?** Remains the second question **Is there any way to force it to distinguish the cases?** Maybe declaring that they are integer *before the integral* will help to make $m=n$ a non-zero measure subset?